# Errors in Blob Cache in SharePoint 2013 public facing website

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, blob-cache

I have been continously getting the errors in **Publishing Cache**
Our website has developed on `SharePoint 2013` and daily we get more than 2lakh hits, unfortunately I have been getting this cashe related errors from log file for quite a long time, I have seen december CUs or more than that can fix the problems, But I'm unable to understand which CU we are currently using.
To know this I have gone through the Products and patch installation updates from CA but could not understand.

[image]

Please review the image to know my errors and guide me how to resolve it.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Go to  Site settings -> Site collection Object cache -> Reset object cache and select "Force all servers to flush their object cache".

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.

I would like to know will we face any problem if we reset object cashe??
and can we do it in working hours or non working.

Comment: I guess it should not face any problem. But on safe site you can do it in non working hour.

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually wants to know after resetting object cashe do I have to change any settings in object cashe?